# How can I have (g)vim start in insert mode by default (when opening a .txt file)?

Tags: vimrc, insert-mode

I often just need to create a `notes.txt` file in Windows to just quickly paste some text from some other place, save it from the `gvim` UI, and close the file. I want to be able to perform this operation quickly without having to press `i` on the keyboard, and `gvim` is my editor of choice on Windows and all files with the `.txt` extension have been associated with `gvim`.

So, I want to configure my `_Vimrc` so that when a `.txt` file is opened, insert mode is enabled by default. For other files, if at all possible, starting in command mode is preferable as I often start a `gvim` session by jumping to a line number in command mode.

If the above is not possible, then how can I simply configure `gvim` to start in insert mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Sort of a dupe, but the other qu. is more about *nix than Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
autocmd BufRead *.txt startinsert
```

Comment: Documentation for `:startinsert`: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:startinsert